# Deprecation warning in Python, does it make sense here?

Tags: python, pyside2, deprecation-warning, qtablewidgetitem

I'm writing a Python (using 3.8.2 version) app for my project. In the app I use PySide2 to create **QTableWidget** object called *items_tableWidget*. Here's the fragment of my code, which creates **QTableWidgetItem** objects, fills them with my data, makes them not editable by user and puts them into the table:

```
cell = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
cell.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, data)
cell.setFlags(cell.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsEditable)
ui.items_tableWidget.setItem(row_number, column_number, cell)
```

I get this warning when running the code:

```
C:\Users\Deronek\Documents\Qt\SkyblockBazaar\main.py:346: DeprecationWarning: an integer is required (got type PySide2.QtCore.Qt.ItemFlags).  Implicit conversion to integers using __int__ is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.
  cell.setFlags(cell.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsEditable)
```

I am a newbie to Python, but I think this warning doesn't make sense, because *setFlags* argument, as well as *flags()* return value and *ItemIsEditable* enum value all have defined types and operators in Qt namespace, so I am not performing an implict conversion. Am I right or I am missing something?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3.8 there has been [the following change](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#other-language-changes):

> Constructors of int, float and complex will now use the __index__()
>   special method, if available and the corresponding method __int__(),
>   __float__() or __complex__() is not available. (Contributed by Serhiy Storchaka in bpo-20092.)

And PySide2 uses the ints to map the enumerations and it has already been reported [PYSIDE-1226](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1226). And as they point out in the comments in the next release, that warning will no longer be released.

In general you shouldn't have a problem and just get that annoying warning.